How to dynamically change which site is servered
I have a scenario where I need to basically deliver a different website based on the time of year. In Dec they want a Christmas site delivered, other wise the regular one. To the visitor they shouldn't see anything different in the routing/address bar. http://localhost/index.php should stay the same weather December or not.
Checking is it's December is fairly easy $isDecember = (date(m)===12)?true:false;
My questions is: Where to do the switching?

Somehow in the bootstrap index.php?
Somehow in the config files?

Changing the default route/controller, I think would change the address bar.


Change each Controller/Action? View? (In a large site this would be a real pain!)
Use Scenarios?
In Apache .htaccess file?
In vhost config file?
Is it possible to do it in one place?

If it was just a "theme" thing, then changing which css file is sent from the layout/main.php would be easy. But some of the actual content needs to be different (Customer comments to Christmas facts, etc.)
The two sites are built and can be mounted similar to the frontend/backend directory structure of the advanced template.
\--main htdocs folder
  |- Main site web folder
  |- Xmas site web folder

or under views
\--Main folder
 |- views
  |- site
  |- xmas

Currently we have to go into the DNS records and make manual changes for a month then change it back.
I've been thinking about this for a couple of weeks and still got nothing :(

Themes might be what you are looking for. It allows you to replace some (or all) view templates. You should be able to create "xmas" version of views as theme. You can use the condition you've mentioned in config file to dynamically set up theme usage.

Themes has always confused me. Do you have to copy all the views? What will YII do if some are missing?

Themes in YII always seemed to be a "set it and forget it" kind of thing. I was never able to wrap my head around changing it dynamically. It seemed like I had to provide every view in the Theme. That seemed to go against the write-once use-many philosophy of programming.

If the theme is set then view template files that exist in theme will be used from theme. For view templates that doesn't exist in theme the basic view template file will be used. So only changed view templates need to exist in theme.

You could have a cron job changing the site configuration within your server(s) to do this; and not changing it in the code; but the actual implementation will be based on which server you are using.
for testing you could actually create two bash scripts:

one to change the site (which can be run manually for testing)
another for checking the date and running the other script (for testing you could just print something in the cli here)

